# Handle paste event in vue2-editor

Tags: vue.js, wysiwyg, paste, quill

I'm using this text editor https://github.com/davidroyer/vue2-editor that is based on Quilljs

I want to handle the paste event so it pastes only the plain text without any format but seems in the documentation that paste is not a supported event by default.

**Is there any way to add the paste event?**

I've already tried using v-on:paste in the Editor and adding the Quill custom module Clipboard but haven't had any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't find a way of doing it with the library I did it with the DOM

```
onPaste() {
  const x = document.getElementById("removePasteFormat");
  console.log(x);
  x.addEventListener("paste", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    let text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
    // access the clipboard using the api
    if (document.queryCommandSupported("insertText")) {
      document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
    } else {
      document.execCommand("paste", false, text);
    }
  });
},
```

Added the id to the div containing the text editors like this:

```
<div id="removePasteFormat"> *<<Here goes the text editor component>>* </div>
```

And register the method on mounted()

```
mounted() {
    this.onPaste();
},
```

Comment: Anybody found a solution for this? Above code doesnt work for  me

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering the same and came up with the following solution.

1 - Use the `:editorOptions` option [referenced here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-editor)

```
<template>
  VueEditor(:editorOptions="editorSettings")
</template>
```

2 - Fill with the module.clipboard module with the option [described here](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#addmatcher)

3 - You can then handle the paste with your personal function (applied after quill's matcher). I've written mine following [this answer on github](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1184#issuecomment-384935594)

```
<script>
  data() {
    return {
      editorSettings: {
        modules: {
          clipboard: {
            matchers: [[Node.ELEMENT_NODE, this.customQuillClipboardMatcher]]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    customQuillClipboardMatcher(node, delta) {
      delta.ops = delta.ops.map((op) => {
        return {
          insert: op.insert
        }
      })
      return delta
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be good to make a plugin.
I made it simple.

src/utils/vue2Plugin/clipboard.ts

```
import Delta from 'quill/node_modules/quill-delta';
import Clipboard from 'quill/modules/clipboard';
import { Quill } from 'vue2-editor';

export class CustomClipboardPlugin extends Clipboard {
  public quill!: Quill;
  public options: any = {};
  constructor(quill: Quill) {
    super(quill, {
      matchers: [],
    });
    this.quill = quill;
    this.quill.root.addEventListener('paste', this.onPaste.bind(this), true);
  }

  onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    const range = this.quill.getSelection(true);
    if (range === null) return;

    let _textHtml;
    if (event.clipboardData?.getData('text/html')) {
      _textHtml = event.clipboardData?.getData('text/html');
    } else if (event.clipboardData?.getData('text/plain')) {
      _textHtml = `<p>${event.clipboardData?.getData('text/plain')}</p>`;
    }
    if (_textHtml) {
      const pastedDelta = this.quill.clipboard.convert(_textHtml);
      const delta = new Delta()
        .retain(range.index)
        .delete(range.length)
        .concat(pastedDelta);
      this.quill.updateContents(delta, Quill.sources.USER);
      this.quill.setSelection(delta.length() - range.length, 0, Quill.sources.SILENT);
    }
  }
}
```

vue file

```
<template>
...
<VueEditor
  ...
  :custom-modules="customModulesForEditor"
  ...
/>
...
</template>

// script
import CustomClipboardPlugin fro 'src/utils/vue2Plugin/clipboard.ts';

...
data() {
  return {
        customModulesForEditor: [{ alias: 'clipboard', module: CustomClipboardPlugin }],
  };
},
...
```